# Одіяло - літературне слово, розмовне чи взагалі калька з російської?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники

Знайшла 3 різні інформації:

1. [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0):

   > Слово «**одіяло**» ***запозичене з російської мови*** — від одеяло (у старому правопису одѣяло), утвореного від дієслова одѣять («одягнути», «одіти»).
2. [Орфографічний словник української мови](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=21&t=203916):

   > **одіяло** - іменник середнього роду, ковдра, ***розм.***
3. [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/odijalo):

   > **ОДІЯ́ЛО**, а, сер. Те саме, що ковдра. Часто він брав лінійку і виглажував [вигладжував] нею скарбове біле з синіми берегами одіяло так, що на ліжку не було і складочки (Нечуй-Левицький, I, 1950, 342).

Отож одіяло - літературне слово, розмовне чи взагалі калька з російської?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Етимологічний словник](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=160) надає:

> **одія́ло** «ковдра», *одія́льник*, *підодія́льник*; — запозичення з російської мови; р. *одея́ло* є похідним від др. *одѣяти* «одягати», пов’язаного з *дѣти* «класти, подіти». — Див. ще **діти²**.

Однак, як Ви вже зазначили, є багато різної інформації. Для знаходження детальнішої — перегляньте «[Як перекласти з російської **пододеяльник**?](/q/310/354)».

Отже, висновок: **одіяло** — це запозичення з російської мови, яке за певний час стало літературним в українській мові (згідно з академічним виданням СУМ).

Comment: @follower, а якщо не секрет, чому Ви змінили «отже, можна зробити висновок, що…» на «отже, висновок: що…» і «опираючись на академічне видання СУМу» на «згідно з академічним виданням СУМ»? По-моєму, оригінальні формулювання були теж цілком прийнятні. Чому не залишити оригінальний стиль автора?

Comment: @Sasha 1) мені здалосьа дешчо на повтор: «отже» та «можна можна зробити висновок» мајуть однакового забарвленьа, хотів зменшити «воду»; 2) Змінив вираз, аби прибрати _у_ післьа _СУМ_, бо так красивіше виглядає.  • Однак, це не головні виправлнньа, а: виправленньа вигльаду (не вистачало підриски) і повтор слова «інформаціја». А так, пишіть јак бажајете, завше можете змінити чи відмінити післьа мене.

Comment: @follower, так, я бачу, що це не основні виправлення. Але я б на Вашому місці не змінював щось, що не є однозначно одруком/помилкою — бо людині може бути неприємно, якщо вона навмисне пише в якомусь одному стилі, а це виправляють на інший. Хоча, якщо чесно, я не знаю, наскільки ця порада узгоджена з офіційними політиками SE, це суто моя думка як людини.

Comment: @Sasha Мају сумнів шчодо навмисності тут, скоріш јакась звичка. Але јак вже написав, можете самі собі виправльати чи повертати — мајете на це повні права, ја сам так инколи робив.